# How to eliminate digits followed by specific string

Tags: c#, regex

I have quite a long regex pattern. Here is just a part of it:

```
string pattern = @"((?<!top=)(?<![A-Za-z])\d)+";
```

Given the string:

```
date(Account/AccountClose) gt 2019-03-25 and Brg eq '100'&$select=IdAccountCurrent&$skip=10&$top=10
```

It matches `2019, 03, 25, 100, 10 and 0`.

I want to eliminate the last `0` from the matching result. In other words, all numbers that are followed by `top=` should not match.

My solution works only if I have one digit after `top=`.How can I achieve the desired result ?

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/RnXfOL/2)

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately, the suggested solutions are not suited for the whole pattern. I tried to make my example simple but it looks like it's imposible to do.

So my whole regex pattern is:

```
string pattern = @"((?<!top=)(?<![A-Za-z])\d|-|T\d+|:|\.|\+|(?<=\d)Z)+|\bfalse\b|\btrue\b|\bnull\b|'[^']+'|\(['\d][^\)]+\)";
```

I need to edit this pattern to eliminate all digits right after `top=`.

[my whole example](https://regex101.com/r/METbbB/2/) (please see the last row in this example, last `0` should not be matched)

Answer (score 2):

You can change your regex to this where I've used `\b` to reject the partial matching of digits,

```
(?<!top=)(?<![A-Za-z])\b\d+
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RnXfOL/3)**

The way your wrote your regex `((?<!top=)(?<![A-Za-z])\d)+` will work by applying the condition on an individually and then counting one or more such characters which wouldn't have allowed using `\b` in your regex and hence I changed it to remove outer parenthesis and used `\b\d+`. Hopefully this should give you all your desired matches. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `0-9` in your regex, for forcing the digit not to be preceded by another digit:

```
((?<!top=)(?<![A-Za-z0-9])\d+)
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/jV0825/1) for a demo.

But you can also just use word boundaries:

```
(?<!top=)\b(\d+)
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/jV0825/2) for a demo.

Comment: Note `\b` is more restrictive since `\b\d` will never match a digit after `_`.